# PHP: Shorthand if - result does not show complete value

Tags: php, html

I dont understant why the second value in my button is not completely displayed

```
<p><input type ="button" id="comment" 
        value=<?php echo $comment_exist == null ? 'Save' : 'Cancel my comment'; ?>></p>
```

if condition is true,  `Save` is displayed
if not  `Cancel` is displayed  but `not my comment`.

Do you know why ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Look at the resulting HTML!

Comment: @Amal  yes because otherwise I wouldnt have the value Cancel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'l need to quote your values. Either in single quote or double. And always have a practice of closing "self-closing" tags  `/>`

```
<p>
 <input type ="button" id="comment" 
    value="<?php echo $comment_exist == null ? 'Save' : 'Cancel my comment'; ?>" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ravi. It works.  Amal who delete his response because false, has put -1 in the post, I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adding quotes)

```
<p><input type ="button" id="comment" 
        value="<?php echo $comment_exist == null ? 'Save' : 'Cancel my comment'; ?>"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote this php code like this may be it will work

```
<p><input type ="button" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment_exist == null ? 'Save' : 'Cancel my comment'; ?>"></p>
```